# Array Function. Would appreciate a little clarification

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a question regarding a school lab assignment and I was hoping someone could clarify this a little for me. I'm not looking for an answer, just an approach. I've been unable to fully understand the books explanations.

> **Question:** In a program, write a function that accepts three arguments: an array, the size of the array, and a number n.
>   Assume that the array contains integers. The function should display
>   all of the numbers in the array that are greater than the number n .

This is what I have right now:

```
/*
Programmer: Reilly Parker
Program Name: Lab14_LargerThanN.cpp
Date: 10/28/2016
Description: Displays values of a static array that are greater than a user inputted value.
Version: 1.0
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void arrayFunction(int[], int, int); // Prototype for arrayFunction. int[] = array, int = size, int = n

int main()
{  
    int n; // Initialize user inputted value "n"
    cout << "Enter Value:" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    const int size = 20; // Constant array size of 20 integers.
    int arrayNumbers[size] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24}; // 20 assigned values for the array

    arrayFunction(arrayNumbers, size, n); // Call function
    return 0;
}    

/*  Description of code below:

The For statement scans each variable, if the array values are greater than the 
variable "n" inputted by the user the output is only those values greater than "n."
*/

void arrayFunction(int arrayN[], int arrayS, int number) // Function Definiton
{
    for (int i=0; i<arrayS; i++) 
    {    
        if (arrayN[i] > number)
        {

        cout << arrayN[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;

        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help without giving out too much :) . Is the question in italics at the top the full topic of your assignment?

Comment: *The function should display all of the numbers in the array that are greater than the number `n`.* This implies that you are not required/expected to read from `cin` in the function.

Comment: Don't make the loop count to 20.  Make the loop count to `size`.  If the array that is passed has less than 20 slots, you will be writing beyond the array, causing *undefined behavior*.

Comment: The `arrayFunction` should refer to `nums[i]` not `values`.

Comment: _"The function should **display** all of the numbers in the array that are greater than the number n ."_ The why is your function body dealing with input rather than output (display)? Isn't that piece of code better placed in `main`?

Comment: Did you even try compiling your function? It has errors that the compiler will report, so how could it possibly be right?

Comment: You should have braces around whatever you want to happen in that `for` loop. Without the braces it will only execute one line in the loop, hence it will print `Enter Values for array` 20 times and will not allow you to input 20 ints. Not that it would work with the current code anyway.

Comment: Do you want to `arrayFunction` *asks user to input values*? Or to *display* them?

Comment: @Lehu          What I really don't want is for this community to think I'm just trying to get a quick answer to avoid the work. If you can give me an example I'd more than appreciate it. I'm really trying to understand this stuff and it wasn't until functions and now arrays that I started getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my whole answer I assume that this:

> **Question**: In a program, write a function that accepts three arguments: an array, the size of the array, and a number n. Assume that the array contains integers. The function should display all of the numbers in the array that are greater than the number n .

is the whole assignment.

1. `void arrayFunction(int[], int, int);` is probably the only thing you could write. Note however that `int[]` is in fact `int*`.
2. As others pointed out don't bother with receiving input. Use something along this line: `int numbers[] = {2,4,8,5,7,45,8,26,5,94,6,5,8};`. It will create static array for you;
3. You have parameter `int n` but you never use it.
4. You are trying to send `variable` to the function `arrayFunction` but I can't see definition of this variable!
5. Use something called **rubber duck debugging** (google for it :) ). It will really help you.

If you have some more precise question, ask them.

As a side note: there are better ways of sending an array to the function, but your assignment forces you to use this old and not-so-good solution.

> Would you use an if else statement? I've edited my original post with the updated code.

You have updated question, then I update my answer.

**First and foremost of all: do indent your code properly!!!**
If you do that, your code will be much cleaner, much more readable, and it will be much easier understandable not only for us, but primairly for you.

Next thing: do not omit braces even if they are not required in some context. Even experienced programmers only rarely omit them, so as a beginner you should never do so (as for example with your `for` loop).

Regarding if-else statement the short answer is: it depends.
Sometimes I would use `if` (note: in your case `else` is useless). But other times I would use ternary operator: `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false;` or even a lambda expression.
In this case you should probably settle for an `if`, as it will be easier and more intuitive for you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I think I've almost got it! I'm only confused how to output the array values that are greater than the user inputted n value. Would you use an if else statement? I've edited my original post with the updated code.

Comment: @ReillyParker It's much better now. I will update my answer.

Comment: Got it! Code functioning properly now. Thanks so much for the help! I'll update my code if you wanna give any last minute pointers. ;) I really appreciate the time you took. Looking at the code now it looks so basic and I'm laughing at myself for making it seem like a bigger ordeal than it turned out to be.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the C++ aspect, think about the steps you need to do to figure out if a number is greater than a certain value.  Then do that for all the numbers in the array, and print out the number if it's greater than n.  Since you have a 'for' loop, it looks like you already know how to do a loop and compare numbers in C++.

Also, it looks like in your arrayFunction you are trying to input values?  You can't input a whole array's worth of values in a single statement like you appear to be trying (also, 'values' is not the name of any variable in arrayFunction, so that would not be recognized when you try to compile it).